# Problems with Huawei me909u521 modem in Raspberry Pi 3 b+

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, connection, raspberry-pi-os, modem

I have the Huawei me909u521 modem attached to RPi 3 b+ via sixfab LTE hat (connected by GPIO).

The Rpi is detecting the modem:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1573 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

pi@raspberrypi:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656
 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x4
0000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=8810a729-02 r
ootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait ip=192.168.0.102 quiet splash ply
mouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000301] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.729840] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a P
L011 rev2
[    9.398372] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    9.399005] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    9.399515] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[    9.400025] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

But not adding a new interface for the modem in order to get IP address later on by AT commands.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:febf:a727  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:bf:a7:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3502  bytes 409754 (400.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59801576  bytes 3229480227 (3.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1524  bytes 59436 (58.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1524  bytes 59436 (58.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:ea:f2:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Shoul I see from the beginning the wwan0 interface for the modem or something is missing to apply?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would check with your supplier the board supports your modem and what driver it needs if it does.  The tech manual does not list your device specifically and states *needs the driver of the compatible module that will be used with the Base HAT* https://docs.sixfab.com/docs/raspberry-pi-3g-4g-lte-base-hat-technical-details#section-compatible-mini-pc-ie-modules